# PostgreSQL slowness in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I need to authenticate a user, so I call this function:

```
db.authenticate = function(username,password)
{
    var query = this.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+username.toLowerCase()+"' AND password = crypt('"+password+"',password);");
    var found = false;
    query.on('row', function(row) {
      found = true;
      console.log("Found:",row.username);
    });       
    if(found){return true;}else{return false;}
}
```

The problem is, that the function doesn't wait for query.on('row') to finish and just return false..

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an asynchronous function, you need to get your results from a callback.

```
db.authenticate = function(username, password, callback) {
    var query = this.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username.toLowerCase() + "' AND password = crypt('" + password + "',password);");
    query.on('row', function(row) {
        console.log("Found:", row.username);
        return callback(true);
    });
    callback(false);
}
```

Then you'd call it like so:

```
db.authenticate(username, password, function (isAuthenticated) {
    console.log(isAuthenticated); //Will be either true or false.
}
```